# Docker containers on Debian Buster are not accessible outside. How do I fix it?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, odoo, debian-buster

I am not sure what happened but I can't seem to be able to access any of my containers anymore. I upgraded Docker today and since then I cant access my containers. I even restarted my server after the upgrade.

I thought that I should rename /var/lib/docker and rebuild my docker containers which worked in the past. However this time that does not work either.

I am able to rebuild an run a container, at least it seems that way, but that is pretty much it. I am unable to access the running container's web pages.

Here I am running Odoo (via docker-compose up using Odoo's default docker build), as you can see it seemed to build fine and running ok. But I can't access it from my desktop.

This was running perfect for a while :(

`Docker version 18.09.1, build 4c52b90, 4.19.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.12-1 (2018-12-22) x86_64`

Docker log
https://pastebin.com/EKNM8FZQ

Daemon log
https://pastebin.com/9xNp7i9r

```
5c4ba56376d2: Pull complete
ee278417002a: Pull complete
81f7195d84c8: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:ba307a52682f1d70ac5d213c545525ed74eb75a87932412a9e51e9663d0bae92
Status: Downloaded newer image for odoo:12.0
Creating odoo_db_1 ... done
Creating odoo_web_1 ... done
Attaching to odoo_db_1, odoo_web_1
web_1  | 2019-03-04 21:23:07,145 1 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 12.0-20190128
web_1  | 2019-03-04 21:23:07,145 1 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at /etc/odoo/odoo.conf                                                                                              
web_1  | 2019-03-04 21:23:07,145 1 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/var/lib/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/12.0', '/mnt/extra-addons', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons']             
web_1  | 2019-03-04 21:23:07,145 1 INFO ? odoo: database: odoo@db:5432
web_1  | 2019-03-04 21:23:07,254 1 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf                                           
web_1  | 2019-03-04 21:23:07,405 1 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 1ef64d047674:8069                                                                          
db_1   | 2019-03-04 21:23:07.432 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1   | 2019-03-04 21:23:07.432 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1   | 2019-03-04 21:23:07.461 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"                                                                                  
db_1   | 2019-03-04 21:23:07.632 UTC [24] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-03-04 21:16:12 UTC                                                                                     
db_1   | 2019-03-04 21:23:09.303 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'                                                                                                                                                                                
  services:                                                                                                                                                                                   
    web:                                                                                                                                                                                      
      image: odoo:12.0                                                                                                                                                                        
      depends_on:                                                                                                                                                                             
        - db                                                                                                                                                                                  
      ports:                                                                                                                                                                                  
        - "4040:8069"                                                                                                                                                                         
      volumes:                                                                                                                                                                                
        - /media/docker/odoo/odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo                                                                                                                                    
        - /media/docker/odoo/config:/etc/odoo                                                                                                                                               
        - /media/docker/odoo/addons:/mnt/extra-addons                                                                                                                                       
    db:                                                                                                                                                                                       
      image: postgres:10                                                                                                                                                                      
      environment:                                                                                                                                                                            
        - POSTGRES_DB=postgres                                                                                                                                                                
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo                                                                                                                                                              
        - POSTGRES_USER=odoo                                                                                                                                                                  
        - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata                                                                                                                                              
      volumes:                                                                                                                                                                                
        - /media/docker/odoo/odoo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata                                                                                                                   
  volumes:                                                                                                                                                                                    
    odoo-web-data:                                                                                                                                                                            
    odoo-db-data:
```

ifconfig -a

```
br-1f972a43ba4c: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-41a0112716c5: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.23.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.23.255.255
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 116  bytes 21432 (20.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-56eb88791692: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.22.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.22.255.255
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 190  bytes 38165 (37.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-66bfdbe63aa2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.21.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.21.255.255
        RX packets 2  bytes 56 (56.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 520  bytes 139325 (136.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-9f041a246e19: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.20.255.255
        RX packets 4  bytes 112 (112.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 336  bytes 110540 (107.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-b408882454cc: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.27.255.255
        RX packets 4  bytes 112 (112.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 319  bytes 105039 (102.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-b6cd97aaf79a: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        RX packets 1  bytes 28 (28.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 525  bytes 140319 (137.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        RX packets 3376  bytes 412660 (402.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5676  bytes 6112740 (5.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.11.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.11.255
        RX packets 4435  bytes 589568 (575.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6026  bytes 1310789 (1.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        RX packets 4459940  bytes 6436989773 (5.9 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1670627  bytes 128486493 (122.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth7: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.5.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.5.255
        RX packets 65068  bytes 13710376 (13.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 67679  bytes 25716123 (24.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 84242  bytes 32551544 (31.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 84242  bytes 32551544 (31.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0



vethb0f44ac: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 192  bytes 38577 (37.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethbf32272: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 170  bytes 31475 (30.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Edit:

I do not remember what version I upgraded from because I just did apt upgrade. However it should not be too old, I believe it was around 18.08-09 version.

It should not matter to me if the container format has changed with the uprade. Because I deleted /var/lib/docker, so the whole thing is created from scratch with the new version if it is.

I am basically unable to access Odoo (or other containers with their own ports) from `http://192.168.5.100:4040` (from network) or `http:/127.0.0.1:4040` (on the server)

I am also thingking that I am hit by some IP6 issue after seeing this. Maybe docker network is only running on IP6?

```
netstat -ntple|grep -i 4040
tcp6       0      0 :::4040                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          13207517   20885/docker-proxy
```

Edit 2:

I went back to 5:18.09.0~3-0~debian-buster from 5:18.09.3~3-0~debian-buster and everything works again. What has changed such that thi upgrade totally broke all my containers?

Comment: Please supply some more information here. What version of docker did you upgrade from? If it was very old, the default storage-driver might have changed. What URL are you visiting on your local machine? Is there nothing in the logs if you attempt to access the webserver. What is the error in the browser? Blank page? Error 500?

Comment: I added a bit more details to my post. I see no activity in the terminal (one running docker-compose up). My suspicion is that I cant even access to the network running docker. I am accessing it like http://192.168.5.100:4050, which was running fine for a month or so. See the new ifconfig paste in my post for network details. I am able to access the server in every other way (SSH, HTTP, HTTPS etc) Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: There was a typo in my reply It is actually  192.168.5.100:4040

Comment: Have you checked the docker daemon log perhaps? I might reveal something. (On debian: /var/log/daemon.log)

Comment: I am really not sure since I do not  know much about docker, however I added related logs to the original post. thanks

Comment: 5:18.09.0~3-0 works but 5:18.09.3~3-0 breaks all my containers

Comment: Check the changelog from 18.09.0 to 18.09.3. Seems like there are some networking changes. https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/. Perhaps you have found a bug or regression?

Comment: Thanks, even if I did not find a bug, it seems like I hit one.